# Pegar Variavel de um Config diretamente em em outro Config

Tags: c#, winforms, app.config

Uma duvida. É possível pega o valor de uma variável de um config diretamente dentro do outro config? Exemplo possível abaixo.

Config1.config:

```
<add key="webservice" value="http.teste.com" />
```

Config2.config:

```
<add key="webservice" value="Config1.config:key("webservice").value" />
```

São configs de WinForms C#

Comment: Em vez de colocar isso: `Config1.config:key("webservice").value` coloca no config2 a chave do config1, no caso o `"webservice"`. Acho que fica mais limpo, no código você criar um método para buscar isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso.
Os valor nos arquivos de configuração são estáticos, tanto que se você tiver uma aplicação Web e editar o Web.config, a aplicação sofre um restart para "pegar" os novos valores, a não ser que você especifique `restartOnExternalChanges="false"`.